# Arranging balls in boxes

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We have $n_1$ number of balls each labelled by the number $1$, $n_2$ number of balls each labelled $2$,..., $n_k$ number of balls each labelled $k$. In how many ways can we permute them in $r$ number of boxes assuming each box can hold exactly $1$ ball.

Edit:

Finding permutations for $n_1$ + $n_2$ + ... + $n_k$ = $r$ would be the same as finding permutations with repetition. Moreover if we have $n_1$ + $n_2$ + ... + $n_k$ < $r$ we may introduce $r$ - ($n_1$ + $n_2$ + ... + $n_k$) balls of another type and find permutations with repetition for $r$ total balls. So finding permutations for $n_1$ + $n_2$ + ... + $n_k$ > $r$ would be enough to answer this question.

Comment: **Hint:** How many ways are there to permute $N$ objects in $r$ ways given that there are $n_k$ repetitions in the $N$ objects for each $k$ ?

Comment: @HDatta -  I didn't get the significance of adding  $r$ - ($n_1$ + $n_2$ + ... + $n_k$) balls when total balls $< r$. Would you pls write down your solution for this case!

Comment: @KGhatak By adding extra balls the total no. of balls become $r$. These new balls just represent empty boxes. So permutation with repetition for $r$ balls should give us the solution for this case.

Comment: @HDatta - So, are you saying # of ways arranging 2 red and 3 blue balls in 5 boxes is same as the # ways we can arrange a red and a blue balls in 5 boxes? Not sure if I'm missing anything! maybe writing exact answer might eliminate the confusion!!

Comment: @KGhatak - The balls added are of another kind acting just as empty sapces. For example if we want to find all arrangements for $n_1$ = $2$, $n_2$ = $3$ and $r$ = $7$ then we may introduce $n_3$ = $2$ balls of another kind and find permutations for $r$ total balls with repetitions.

Comment: @HDatta - Well, I got the point. Your logic works, and in fact, the same solution is also depicted by Donald Splutterwit.

Answer (score 0):

We have $ \sum_{i=1}^{k} n_i \leq r$. There are $ \binom{r}{n_1}$ ways to place the $1$'s. Then there are $ \binom{r-n_1}{n_2}$ ways to place the $2$'s. ... multiplying these binomial coefficients together gives the multinomial coeffiecient

\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{r}{n_1 , n_2, \cdots , n_k,r-\sum_{i=1}^{k} n_i}. 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I didn't specify that n_1 + n_2 +...+n_k add up to r. They could be equal greater than or lesser than r.

Comment: Thank you for responding earlier. I know that I am late but I still updated my question to clarify things a bit. Could you please have a look at this question again?